# Библиотеки для работы с консольным интерфейсом в C++

Tags: c++

Хотелось бы узнать, как называется такой интерфейс, и есть ли для работы с ним библиотеки для C++/C. Наткнулся на такую библиотеку для Python: http://urwid.org/, хотелось бы узнать о таких библиотеках для C++/C.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: когда-то такое можно было сделать на Borland C++, сейчас даже не знаю :) делать надо все ручками. а вообще это обычный shell интерфейс для DOS

Comment: ncurses же, его, в частности, может mc использовать.

Comment: ncureses для linux. а тут вопрос походу про DOS. Если вспомню скажу

Comment: Вам под какую платформу-то?

Answer (score 4):

Вы привели примеры из времен DOS. В те времена была популярна библиотека [Turbo Vision](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision). Были ее версии для Borland Turbo C и Turbo Pascal.

В наше время текстовые интерфейсы используют обычно только терминальные программы Unix систем (включая linux) - это ncurses и slang. В принципе, эти библиотеки смогут работать и под cygwin, если захочется на них что-то писать под windows, но imho это какой-то странный путь.

Comment: Turbo Vision тоже уже открыта, даже порты есть под разные платформы. Правда про качество не скажу :) http://www.sigala.it/sergio/tvision/index.html и http://tvision.sourceforge.net/